# Unable to manage CiviCase cases

Tags: civicase

I've installed CiviCRM, and made sure my Drupal 8 role settings give Admins full permissions for CiviCRM.

I am able to create cases for constituents, but cannot do anything else such as add Activities, Timelines, sort/filter by status, or see whatever is behind the hamburger menu beside the status, access the settings on the Activities tab, etc.

On the Summary tab there is a "Tasks" section but from the documentatio, I don't know what that's for and I don't see any option to add a task.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using shoreditch then this might be the problem as currently it's not guaranteed to work on drupal 8.

It is a requirement for the CiviCase extension - but you can use CiviCase component without the extension.

Comment: I am, since it's required for CiviCase. I had no idea it wasn't compatible. What can I do?

Comment: It's required for the civicase extension but you can use core civicase. You don't need the civicase extension to manage cases.

Comment: Is there any way to use CiviCRM without Shoreditch?

Comment: what's core civicase?

Comment: Just uninstall the civicase extension and shoreditch.